# Backbone JS Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In a youtube tutorial I saw a different way of declaring a model:

```
model = Backbone.Model({
data:[
    {text:"Google", href:"https://google.com"},
    {text:"Facebook", href:"https://facebook.com"},
    {text:"Youtube", href:"https://youtube.com"}
  ]

});
```

my console log is throwing error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'set'

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You need to instantiate `Backbone.Model` with `new`. Also, are you sure you don't mean to use `Backbone.Collection`? You're passing an array of multiple objects...

Comment: @willM Thanks for pointing out that silly mistake about new. Also I am new to backbone. I am yet to reach collections tutorial ;) I will use that soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    data:[
        {text:"Google", href:"https://google.com"},
        {text:"Facebook", href:"https://facebook.com"},
        {text:"Youtube", href:"https://youtube.com"}
   ]
});
```

So, as related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093209/new-backbone-model-vs-backbone-model-extend), creating a `Bakbone.Model()` means the creation of a custom model, and as you appear wanting, to create a Model you need to use `Backbone.Model.extend()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that link which cleared the difference. I was thinking why that tutorial didn't use extend. Now I know.